# Determine whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{x} a_kn^k}{e^n}$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The task is to show whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{x} a_kn^k}{e^n}$ for some $x \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and some coefficients $a_1, ..., a_x \in \mathbb{C}$ is converging or diverging. My only idea is to use the Ratio test for this, but my mind is blocked by how to simplify the expression such that it becomes easier to solve.

I would appreciate it a lot if someone has an idea on how to start off.

Best regards!

Comment: What do you know about the $a_k$? Also, is the upper limit on the inner sum supposed to be $x$?

Comment: @martycohen Thanks for the input, I edited my post to clarify. Yes, the upper limit should be some x in the natural numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the partial sums.

$\begin{array}\\
s(m)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac{\sum_{k=0}^{x} a_kn^k}{e^n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m} e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{x}a_kn^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{x}\sum_{n=1}^{m} e^{-n}a_kn^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{x}a_k\sum_{n=1}^{m} e^{-n}n^k\\
&\sim\sum_{k=0}^{x}a_kk!
\qquad\text{(by comparison with }\int_0^{\infty} e^{-y}y^k dy = k!\\
\end{array}
$

Since this is a finite sum,
this converges.

As $x \to \infty$,
the convergence or divergence
depends on the $a_k$.